# How to align the contents parallelly in minipage

Tags: minipage

I am unable to align the contents parallelly on the same page. the part which I need to include on the right side of a page comes into the right side of the second page though the right side of the first page is still empty. I a hereby enclosing the image as well.

```
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[t]{11cm}
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to right by = 0.75cm,colframe=white,colback=white]
        \section*{Education}
            \begin{tabular}{r l}
            xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
                                  & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx : & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
                                  & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
            
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example instead of a code snippet.

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem. Which contents you like to align paralel. Code fragment has only a table in which bot columns are  properly aligned.

Comment: I am trying to make a two-column CV. I have included my skills on the left side. I would like to include my education details and experiences on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

You can place two minipages side by side with a total width less than the width of the text.

Inside you have the tabular environment. Setting a `p` column takes care of a long line formatting so you don't need to add another row for the same entry.

[image: a]

This is the complete code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}%% adjust margins

\usepackage{showframe}%only to see the margins

\begin{document}
    
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\section*{Skills}
    \small
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% increase space between rows
    \begin{tabular}{r p{0.45\linewidth}}
        xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: & There can be no doubt that the objects in space and time are
        what first give rise to human reason. \\                
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx : & Let us suppose that, indeed, our
        problematic judgements, indeed, can be treated like our concepts.\\                                 
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\section*{Education}
    \small
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% increase space between rows
    \begin{tabular}{r p{0.45\linewidth}}
        xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: & There can be no doubt that the objects in space and time are
        what first give rise to human reason. \\                
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx : & Let us suppose that, indeed, our
            problematic judgements, indeed, can be treated like our concepts.\\                                 
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

    
\end{document}
```